# Equivalent of /etc/sysconfig/clock in redhat 7

Tags: linux, rhel

I cannot find /etc/sysconfig/clock in redhat 7. Is there any equivalent file in redhat7??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a RedHat 7 system you can use the [timedatectl utility](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Configuring_the_Date_and_Time.html).

For example

```
# timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Rome
```

to set the system time zone (it manages the `/etc/localtime` symlink)

```
# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 33 Jun 30 17:59 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome
```

or

```
# timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
```

to maintain the RTC in universal time (it changes the 3rd line of `/etc/adjtime`)